# Как добавить и удалить блок div?

Tags: javascript, html

Форма, в которой есть div с id="field", где addElement() добавляет элементы в div с id='content'.
Мне нужно задействовать кнопки "Удалить" div c id="field" и "Добавить" такой же div после div c id="field".
Я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы в новом диве кнопка "Удалить" удаляла div которому принадлежит.

```
<form>  
    <div id="field">
        <textarea placeholder="Заголовок поля"></textarea>
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="addElement();">
            <option value='textarea'>Один из списка</option>
            <option value='input'>Текст-строка</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Удалить"><br>
        <div id='content'>

        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить"><br><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function removeField(btn) {
  var div = btn.closest(".field");
  if (div) {
    div.remove();
  }
}

function addField(btn) {
  var form = btn.closest("form");
  if (form) {
    var div1 = form.querySelector(".field");
    if (div1) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = div1.className;
      div.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML;
      form.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.field:first-child {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form>  
    <div class="field">
        <textarea placeholder="Заголовок поля"></textarea>
        <select class="selectBox" onchange="addElement();">
            <option value='textarea'>Один из списка</option>
            <option value='input'>Текст-строка</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Удалить" onclick="removeField(this)"><br>
        <div class='content'>

        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="addField(this)"><br><br>
</form>
```